# Highcharts bar chart becomes unreadable

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is pretty straight forward.  I've been struggling to get Highcharts to display some charts in a readable manner for a while now and no one seems to be able to give me a good solution.  This is a great example of what's happening:

[image: chart problem]

We have a tool where we dynamically can add and remove data from a chart.  This chart is clearly a very large dataset.  I'm not sure what properties I need to manipulate in Highcharts to prevent this sort of chart from being generated.  If anyone can shed some light, I'd be forever in your debt.

Comment: You should include in your question a sample of how you would like the graph to look and perhaps a sample of your code so that users can try to find a solution for you question.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect, how it should be printed ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was straight forward... I mean I don't want the lines to be one pixel thick or less so that the chart is completely unreadable and the user can't interact with it whatsoever.  I'd like the lines to be a normal height with a clear separation between them.

Comment: Use [pointPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.pointPadding) / [groupPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.groupPadding) parameters to adapt to your expectations.